# Passing int variable from Java to C

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, native

I have this two codes
Java:
`public native void savex(int x);`
C:

```
void Java_com_example_javatest_MainActivity_savex(jint x)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/data/data/com.example.javatest/data.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", (int)x);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

When run the result is always having -1265282592 in data.txt.
What's the problem here?

Comment: You need to give more details on the code that calls the C function, that original value of the Java variable etc, otherwise it'll be hard to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> void Java_com_example_javatest_MainActivity_savex(jint x)

The function arguments must be:

```
void Java_com_example_javatest_MainActivity_savex(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,jint x)
```